# Почему не подключается библиотека?

Tags: c#, исключения, dll, типы, assembly

Пробовал компилировать в режиме x32 и x64, ещё я пробовал подключать "KernelBase" и "ntdll"? DLL находятся в папке с запускаемой программой

```
Assembly a = Assembly.Load("kernel32");// Здесь происходит исключение "Вызвано исключение: "System.BadImageFormatException" в mscorlib.dll"
foreach (Type t in a.GetExportedTypes())
{
    if (t.IsPublic && t.Name == "File" && t.Namespace == "System.IO")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.FullName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Есть подозрение, что Assembly.Load может загрузить только .NET-сборку, коей kernel32.dll не является.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Ну а можно как нибудь через winapi.loadlibrary подключить?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy можно, подключайте.

Comment: Конечно можно. Только разрядность должна быть та же, что и у загружающего процесса

Comment: @PavelMayorov хорошо подключить, я смогу, а вот вы не подскажите winapi'шный аналог GetExportedTypes?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy [Dynamically calling an unmanaged dll from .NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jonathanswift/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-net-c/)

Comment: Чтобы можно было получить и вывести все имена экспортируемых "типов" и их адреса

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy нет в WinAPI функции перечисления экспортов, парсинг таблицы экспортов руками - решение проблемы. И никаких экспортируемых типов в kernel32.dll тоже нет, есть сопоставление имя-адрес.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ох, придётся попотеть, ну ладно, спасибо

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy казалось бы, но зачем перечислять экспорты kenel32.dll руками?

Comment: "Все уже украдено до нас", посмотрите тут http://www.pinvoke.net/index.aspx, описано как в коде C# подключить большинство функций WinAPI из соответствующих нативных библиотек. Даже если чего-то нет, можно сделать по аналогии, на основе документации к функции, если она есть конечно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не уверен, но вроде Assembly.Load может загрузить только .NET-сборку, коей kernel32.dll не является.

Comment: Ладно, последний мини-вопрос, как парсить, точнее как получить то-что нужно парсить (байт-код)?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy нет в kernel32.dll никакого байт-кода, только нативный

Comment: Ну нативный как получить, я просто не разу не парсил?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy вам который из? В IMAGE_DOS_HEADER находите значение e_lfanew, по нему лежит IMAGE_NT_HEADERS, в этой структуре поле EnrtyPoint содержит RVA на точку входа в exe/dll/sys-файле. Там уже нативный код. Но зачем?

Comment: А, ну еще нужно правильно понять что там с секциями, чтобы RVA перевести в файловое смещение, если вам нужно без загрузки в память работать. А при загрузке в память нужно ImageBase учитывать

Comment: Смотрите как вам моя идея получить списком все функции из DLL: Берём указатель на строку ptrSTR "______" (пустая строка) и запускаем lpProcName(ptrDLL,ptrSTR), если есть такая функция то добавляем её в какой нибудь список, затем строку делаем "_____a", повторяем тоже самое, дальше делаем строку "_____b" и повторяем тоже самое, ... дальше делаем строку "____ccc" и повторяем ну и т.д.

Comment: Самая изи идея )

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy зачем вам получение списка функций? Есть программы, которые просматривают DLL (можно где нибудь сорсы на гитхабе найти). Решаемый вопрос. Но мне кажется вам нужно заюзать одну или несколько из функций. Для этого необходимо описать их сигнатуру, подгрузить и использовать в коде. Выше Embedder скинул в комментариях как это делается.

Comment: Самая изи-идея - взять HIEW, вырезать в файл директорию экспортов и натравить на нее strings. Полный перебор имени AddIntegrityLabelToBoundaryDescriptor займет чуть больше, чем слишком много

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy в любом случае не понятно зачем вам полный список экспортов во время выполнения. Похоже на "проблему молотка"